# How to know how many request each api handled every day in aws

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have EC2 service (elasticbeanstalk) which my project is located on it. Now Is there any way to see how many requests a specific API handles every day. I'm storing the error, access, ... logs to the cloud watch, Maybe somehow we could use the access logs to see how many requests each API handled every day. But I need to define a chart for it so in one look I could understand, For example, this new endpoint `api/user/allowance` that I have made, there are some customers started using it. So eventually what I need is something like this

Api            |        Total number of requests |  filter_start_date   |    filter_end_date

Comment: If you are using cloudflare, there is a service called `Logpush service`, you may configure your s3 bucket and it will push access logs into s3 in some interval - then you may use `athena` to query them via using 25+ fields including date, url, client ip etc.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using Cloudflare really. but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually I have dig into the problem more, and I've found a solution for it, At least it's works for me. So I went to cloudWatch and then Insights panel, From there I could define a query to group my log messages by their request Url, The log message I have is sth like this

```
0.0.0.0 (11.11.11.11) - - [18/Oct/2019:13:33:49 +0000] "GET api/user/allowance HTTP/1.1" 200 2575 "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"
```

Then I have defined the query to get and group by the Request URL, And after grouping, I counted the grouped.

```
FIELDS @message
| PARSE @message "* [*] * * *" as ipAddresses, requestTime, RequestAction, RequestUrl, RestOfTheLog
| stats count(*) by RequestUrl
```

This way you'll have list of endpoints with total number of requests.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your app is writing the logs to CloudWatch Logs. You can log an unique entrance msg of the restful API you want to trace. Then create a custom metrics for the CloudWatch Log groups with filter matching the entrance msg of API.

See [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html) for how to create custom metrics for CloudWatch Log groups.